# Webform controls are not validated

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a couple of textboxes and some dropdownlists on a register page. When the user presses submit, I want the values to be validated and if they are correct I want to enter them in the database. My values are not being validated, even if I call validation manually and check whether they are valid or not. So my code is putting empty stuff in the DB...

```
    protected void btn_registreren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\Database11.accdb";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Gebruikers(gebruikersnaam, geboortedatum, admin, wachtwoord) VALUES (@gebruikersnaam, @geboortedatum, @admin, @wachtwoord)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gebruikersnaam", txt_email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geboortedatum", txt_dag.Text + "-" + ddl_maand.SelectedValue + "-" + txt_jaar.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", false);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wachtwoord", txt_wachtwoord.Text);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                lblConnState.Text = "Connection is: " + conn.State.ToString();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                lblConnState.Text = exc.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                lblConnState2.Text = "<br />Connection is: " + conn.State.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblConnState2.Text = "not valid";
        }
    }
```

I tried: giving all fields, validators and submit button the same validation group. I tried doing this in the page load as well. Also looked around extensively on the internet but couldn't find what is wrong.

Comment: Post the HTML code where you use the validators.

Comment: Hey a bit late here, sorry about that! I simply removed and readded the validators and now it's working. I just hope it won't happen again when I transfer all the files.